# Sorting a list in python by last number in each element

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with a list like the following:

```
notes = ['G3', 'E2', 'A7', 'E1', 'F4', 'A6', 'B7', 'A4', 'G1', 'A5', 'A2', 'D1', 'B5', 'D7']
```

I want to sort the list by the last number of each item in the list so it returns only the highest numbers.

For example, I want the list to return:

```
notes = ['A7', 'B7', 'D7']
```

Thanks. I am really new to python!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for sorting, but it sounds like you want to filter out specific items.

To sort you can use `sorted()` and use a key function that only looks at the last character:

```
sorted(notes, key=lambda n: n[-1], reverse=True)
```

This will result in all your notes in sorted order by last character:

```
['A7', 'B7', 'D7', 'A6', 'A5', 'B5', 'F4', 'A4', 'G3', 'E2', 'A2','E1','G1','D1']
```

To get just the notes ending in `7`, you could find the max character and then use that to filter out the others:

```
maxDegree = max(note[-1] for note in notes)
# maxDegree is "7"
# use that to filter out the others
[note for note in notes if note[-1] == maxDegree]
# ['A7', 'B7', 'D7']
```